# NGINX alias returning file not found

Tags: linux, nginx, php

I am trying to set up an alias so I can navigate to ww.*.com/dev/ and have it be serving files from out side of the root directory.

Things i've tried

- ensured php block is in location block
- tried replacing alias with root
- tried commenting out  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
- tried the suggested fix for try_files inside of nested blocks.

root - /var/www/nginx/www/a
ailas - /var/www/nginx/www

my alias

```
  location /dev {
           alias /var/www/nginx/www;
               location ~ /([^/]+\.php)$ {
                   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                 # try_files /$1 =404;
                   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                  # fastcgi_index index.php;
                   include fastcgi_params;
               }
       }
```

snippets/fastcgi-php.conf

```
 # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

   # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
   try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

   # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
   # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
   set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

  fastcgi_index index.php;
   include fastcgi.conf;
```

fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
  fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
  fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
  fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
  fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
  fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
  fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

  fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

  fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
  fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
  fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

  # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
  fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Could you please share some logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
location ^~ /dev {
    alias /var/www/nginx/www;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /dev/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Use the `^~` modifier on the `location` block to avoid potential conflicts with other regular expression location blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Avoid using `try_files` and `alias` together because of this [long standing issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

Most of your `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` file is related to the use of pathinfo, which you do not appear to be using.

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.